# Plotting a continuous function as a contour plot

Tags: r

I am looking to create a continuous contour/heat plot based on a function I have created. The plot will be based on given inputs and a x and y limit, then the function produces the heat map with contours at each 0.01 increment.

```
# var 1 to 3 are given as inputs and do not change.
var1 = 3
var2 = 1
var3 = 0.02

# x and y are additional variables, but they are plotted within a range 
# on the chart, xlim = c(0, 24), ylim = c(0, 0.05)

# Given var 1 to 3, and the ranges x and y, plot the result (z) as a heat map and/or contour
result <- function(var1, var2, var3,x, y){
  var2 * (1 + (x/12) * var3) * (1 + -var1 * y)
}

# sample output at point x = 12, y = 0.02, and equals 0.9588 in this example.
result(var1 = 3, var2 = 1,var3 = 0.02,
   x=12, 
   y=0.02)
```

The chart below represents what I am trying to accomplish, though its pulled from a web and unrelated to the data I provided. I have not used continuous functions within a contour plot before.

[image]

Comment: So what is specifically holding you up? Based of what you have so far first problem I see is that if you want to make a color plot using image or image.plot and/or a contour plot you need your function to output x,y,z or a matrix of z values. Right now it is just spitting out 1 number. What you could do is have x and y be actual ranges i.e. x=c(0,3), y=c(-2,1). Also you will need another variable the tells your function how often to calculate over that range. Does it calculate ever 0.5 or 1 etc. This along with x and y will determine how large your output matrix is.

Comment: I need the plot to produce the z values give a range of x and y. The sample I provided is just 1 value because both x and y are given, so it would just be one point on the graph. If I am understanding you correctly, I am not able to produce a continuous plot? I was under the impression this was doable particularly given the plot I provided appears to be continuous

Answer (score 1):

You just need to construct your function correctly and you can do pretty much anything.

```
result <- function(var1, var2, var3,x, y,d){
ydata=numeric(length(seq(y[1],y[2],d)))
mat=matrix(NA,length(seq(y[1],y[2],d)),length(seq(x[1],x[2],d)))
yy=seq(y[1],y[2],d)
xx=seq(x[1],x[2],d)
for(i in 1:length(xx)){
for(n in 1:length(yy)){
ydata[n]=var2 * (1 + (xx[i]/12) * var3) * (1 + -var1 * yy[n])
}
mat[,i]=ydata
}
return(mat)}
```

You `image` is strange so you'll need to rotate your matrix before entering it into `image`. You can use a simple function like this that I got somewhere on stackoverflow.

```
rotate <- function(x) t(apply(x, 2, rev))
```

Then you're ready to plot

```
mydata=result(var1 = 3, var2 = 1,var3 = 0.02,x=c(-1200,1200),y=c(-3005,2008),d=10)
image(rotate(mydata))
par(new=TRUE)
contour(mydata)
```

I'll leave making the plot look nice up to you.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful so far. I need to ask, why are the x and y axes in the plot ranging from 0 to 1 instead of what is specified in the function? Also, I see this is not a continuous plane, should I expect to have to compute a set of z values when I want to make a plot like this? It seems to get slow if I want smooth lines.

Comment: I was able to customize the axes by adding the following code:  x.atRange <- seq(0, 1, length.out=9)
y.atRange <- seq(0, 1, length.out=7) axis(1, at=x.atRange, labels = seq(min(xrange), max(xrange), length.out=length(x.atRange)))
axis(2, at=y.atRange, labels = seq(min(yrange), max(yrange), length.out=length(y.atRange)))

Comment: As far as I know there is no function that will take a two variable equation and give you a plot over some range. You change the axis here but I think you still need to line up the image and the contours. Read the functions `image` and `contours` to learn how to do that. Your getting confused by your terminology, your equation is continuous but no plot can be literally continuous. For that it would have to calculate the value of your function at an infinite number of points. If you want the plot to look better decrease d, and your plot will become finer, more points.